# How to restart a switch menu?

Tags: java

I have a `switch` menu that I would like to restart after completing a `case`. I understand it is done with a`While`loop but the problem is that it starts with the `case 1`

Here is my file UI which has the `switch` menu:

```
     out.println("Choose an option:");
     out.println("1. Array of guests");
     out.println("2. Array of hosts");``

     while(exit == false) {

        // Calls functions defined in CL
         switch(menu){
             ``
             case 1:

                 CL.guests = new String [CL.define_size()];
                 CL.fill_array(CL.guests);

                 break;

             case 2:

                 CL.hosts = new String [CL.define_size()];
                 CL.fill_array(CL.hosts);

                 break;

        }
```

Here is my CL file which has the functions

```
public class CL  {

public static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public static PrintStream out = System.out;

static String [] guests;
static String [] hosts;

//Los arreglos se definen con un método

public static int define_size () throws IOException {

    out.println("Enter the size of the array");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    return number;       
}

public static void fill_array (String parray []) throws IOException{        
    for(int i = 0; i < parray.length; i++){
        out.println("Enter the value of " + (i+1) );
        parray[i] = in.readLine();            
    }                
}

public static void print_array(String [] parray){        
    for(int i = 0; i < parray.length; i++){
        out.println(parray[i]);
    }        
}
```

Output:

```
Choose an option::
1. Register guests
2. Register hosts

//Menu

1
Enter the size of the array
2
Enter the name of value 1
guest1 
Enter the size of the array // why does it loop to case 1 instead of menu?
```

Comment: Unrelated: dont do "someBoolean == true" (or false). Just go `while(!exit)` for example. Or turn it around, to avoid the negation: `while(continueLoop)`

Answer (score 1):

At no point in the code you provided do you read in the value of `menu`, so `menu` is always set to the same value. Also, you print the menu outside of the while loop, so it will only print the menu once.